# WatchConnectivity sendMessage:replyHandler: don't work when linker have flag -ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I have project with some external libraries, this project use -ObjC linker flag for these libraries. Without -ObjC project will crash. And now i want to add support for Watch OS 2. But I have problem: until linker has flag -ObjC method -sendMessage:replyHandler: return error like

```
Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7014 "Payload could not be delivered." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Payload could not be delivered.}
```

I can't delete this flag (-ObjC), but with it my watch doesn't work. If user tap at button I will need send some info to my iPhone. And with another ways sending info I have problems too. System add messages into queue and keep them forever. Anybody have ideas ?

Comment: The watchKit connectivity error has nothing to do with linker flags, I believe. What kind of objects are you trying to send between the watch and the phone? It seems like either you are sending a none-supported object type or you didn't implement delegate method in the receiver (the device that is receiving the message)

Comment: This linker flag can load some third party code. Or framework. It can have blocker code. I try to understand witch code can block WatchConnectivity. I send @{ @"data" : @"for send" }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found reason ! It was Appodeal framework v0.10.2, I attached Applodeal v0.10.3 and now my watch code worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Linker flag should not effect WatchKit connectivity. Here are several troubleshooting procedures.

1. You have to make sure the delegate method is implemented on the device that receives the message.

`-(void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message`

2. In your comments, you said the data that you are sending is a simple dictionary. WatchKit connectivity doesn't allow you to send custom class objects.
3. Also try to restart your simulator or device. Especially with simulators, Watchkit connectivity often fails. Rebuild and restart will help.

These are the usual mistake that people make (or I made) about Wathkit Connectivity. No code should block Watchkit Connectivity. Please read Apple's documentation closely about the specifics of delegates and protocols. Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck!

Comment: I have found reason, look my answer below. Some code from Appodeal library blocked it. I don't know how, but it is. And linker flag made blocker-code loaded.

Answer (score 0):

T_T it's not solved T_T

only the way to fix it from now, turn on the ios app once when occur the error. it might be initializing process as what they said.